# How to update sql column based on matching special character

Tags: t-sql, special-characters

I'm trying to get rid of some bad characters in our database. The rows I'm working on at the moment start with a bullet and a space. My where clause isn't matching the rows in question, however. How can I get a match? This is what I'm currently trying.

```
update Skill
set Name = substring(Name, 3, 50)
where Name like char(150) + ' %'
```

Comment: what do you get when you run `select ASCII(left([Name],1))`?

Comment: D'oh! The character turned out to be 149, as I'm guessing you suspected. Thanks! Damn off-by-one errors!

Comment: No worries @birdus I figured that was it. I gave you a Unicode version below that is more encompassing as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you aren't capturing the correct ASCII value. Here's a way with unicode that uses a similar method.

```
declare @table table ([Name] nvarchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('- some data')

select 
    UNICODE(left([Name],1))        --this will tell you what VALUE to use in the where clause
    ,NCHAR(UNICODE(left([Name],1)))
from @table

update @table
set [Name] = substring([Name], 3, 50)
where UNICODE(left([Name],1)) = 45 --use the appropriate UNICODE values here


select * from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments you can use ASCII() to get the code for the character you are looking for and then use that code in your update.

```
UPDATE Skill
set Name = substring(Name, 3, 50)
WHERE LEFT(name,1) = CHAR(149)
```